# C# library for .NET Core and .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-core

I'm doing a Network library (https://github.com/Eastrall/Ether.Network) for now targeting the .NET Core framework, but I want support both .NET Core and .NET Framework (4.*)

I heard about adding some lines on the `project.json` is this a good solution?

Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: too vague, .net core is much more limited in scope than .NET framework I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: So I can't deploy my library on NuGet for .NET Core and .NET Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, modifying `project.json` is what you need. It should look like:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a scheme of mapping the .NET Platform Standard to platforms of interest from the [official documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md):

[image]

A few quick notes:

> - If a library targets .NET Platform Standard version 1.3, it can only
>     run on .NET Framework 4.6 or later, .NET Core, Universal Windows
>     Platform 10 (UWP), and Mono/Xamarin platforms.
> - If a library targets
>     .NET Platform Standard version 1.3, it can consume libraries from all
>     previous .NET Platform Standard versions (1.2, 1.1, 1.0).
> - The
>     earliest .NET Framework to support a .NET Platform Standard version
>     is .NET Framework 4.5. This is because the new portable API surface
>     area (aka System.Runtime based surface area) that is used as the
>     foundation for the .NET Platform Standard only became available in
>     that version of .NET Framework. Targeting .NET Framework <= 4.0
>     requires multi-targeting.

For further details it is recommended to check out the [official documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md).

Comment: it's probably worth adding that it's best to avoid using netstandard 1.5 or 1.6, as they won't be compatible with netstandard 2.0, which it's available. Netstandard 1.4 or earlier will be compatible with netstandard 2.0, so it's a good choice for making portable libraries now. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/#div-comment-136675

Comment: @Ziv That comment is outdated, see [.NET Framework 4.6.1 supporting .NET Standard 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md#net-framework-461-supporting-net-standard-20). Though it's still preferable to avoid .Net Standard 1.5 and 1.6, because members specific to them won'will fail on .Net 4.6.1 at runtime.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed!