# In NetStandard 1.3: How I get all classes that implement an interface to avoid the Error CS0117 'Assembly' does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, .net-standard

I tried to use this code in a NetStandard 1.3  class library:

```
    foreach (Type mytype in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(mytype => mytype .GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(myInterface)))) {
        //do stuff
     }
```

but a compilation error is raised:

```
    Error   CS0117  'Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'GetExecutingAssembly'
```

I reached [What is the equivalent of Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483189/what-is-the-equivalent-of-assembly-getentryassembly-in-net-core), but it can't help.

I know that this service may be available in NetStandard 2, but until it's released(it's now in preview):

What is the modification to be done to the above code to support NetStandard 1.3

**Update:**

The question isn't a duplicate, i mentioned this link in my question and said it doesn't help.

Based on the comment of @ mjwills, it's probably worth adding that it's best to avoid using netstandard 1.5 or 1.6, as they won't be compatible with netstandard 2.0 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/#div-comment-136675

[C# library for .NET Core and .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527541/c-sharp-library-for-net-core-and-net-framework)

I ask for an equivalent code (not necessary using GetExecutingAssembly):

How I get all classes that implement an interface in NetStandard 1.1 up to 1.4 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483189/what-is-the-equivalent-of-assembly-getentryassembly-in-net-core)

Comment: I mentioned this link in my question , but it can't help.

Comment: The answer there states `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() is available in .NET Standard 1.5, but not in versions 1.0 through 1.4.` You need to use a newer version.

Comment: t's probably worth adding that it's best to avoid using netstandard 1.5 or 1.6, as they won't be compatible with netstandard 2.0 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/#div-comment-136675

Comment: Does `typeof(YourTypeHere).GetTypeInfo().Assembly` work for you? I am unclear if it works in 1.3 or not.

Comment: yes, It is working,and i get Assembly , but i can't find GetTypes. How to get?

Comment: For your update, they changed their minds about the compatability, netstandard 1.5 and 1.6 is compatable with 2.0, from [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md) *".NET Standard 2.0 will be a strict superset of .NET Standard 1.6. In other words, no breaking changes will happen between .NET Standard 2.0 and 1.x."*

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, good news.

Comment: I test the code in  my question AS IS in vs2017.3 preview 3, Netstandard 2 preview and it's Working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is running in NetStandard1.3 and get all classes that implement interface without compilation error:

```
            Assembly asm = typeof(ICustomeAttribute).GetTypeInfo().Assembly; //thanks to @mjwills  for his helpfull comment

            var types = asm.DefinedTypes.Where(x=>x.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(typeof(ICustomeAttribute)));
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                //do stuff
                Console.WriteLine("class name: {0} - {1}",type.Name,type.FullName);
            }
```

**Remarks**

Excerpt from: [Assembly.DefinedTypes Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.definedtypes(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The DefinedTypes property is comparable to the Assembly.GetTypes
>   method, except that the DefinedTypes property returns a collection of
>   TypeInfo objects, and the Assembly.GetTypes method returns an array of
>   Type objects.